# Moving RewriteBase rule in htaccess to httpd.conf

Tags: htaccess, apache, subdirectory

I'm now working in a server environment where I can access and edit `httpd.conf`, which is preferable from a performance and a revision control standpoint. I have a few sites (they are Drupal) running in subdirectories along the lines of `example.com/yourname`, `example.com/anothername`, `example.com/anotherdev`. Right now they have a rewrite rule along the lines of

```
RewriteBase /yourname
```

in each of their `.htaccess` files. This doesn't work in `httpd.conf` and some of the documentation I've been reading says `RewriteBase` is bad to put in `httpd.conf` anyway. Any insight into the right approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have a rewrite base, all you have to do is insert what would have been the base into each of your rewrite rules.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$  welcome.html
```

Becomes

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.html$  /welcome.html
```

Comment: Which RewriteRules do I use to replace RewriteBase?

Comment: You don't "replace" RewriteBase, you remove it, and then edit each end every one of your RewriteRules to add the slash in as I have done in an example.

Comment: There weren't any rewriterules used, just the rewritebase

Comment: There was an alias for the directory (for example yourname site was in the directory yourname123...I didn't set this server up, so I have no idea why)  and when I removed that and then just renamed the subdirectories to their respective names (renamed yourname123 to yourname), it started to work without the rewritebase. I still am curious how to do it with the alias intact though.

Comment: If there are no rewrite rules, the RewriteBase won't have any effect on its own.  It can safely be removed.

Answer (score 0):

> This doesn't work in `httpd.conf` and some of the documentation I've been reading says RewriteBase is bad to put in `httpd.conf` anyway.

As you say, this simply "does not work" - it is wholly invalid (not that it's a "bad practise"). The server will fail to start if you try to use `RewriteBase` in a *server* or *virtualhost* context (ie. directly in the server config).

When using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` (a *directory* context) all *relative* URL-path *substitutions* are relative to the current directory - the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. The `RewriteBase` directive allows you to override the URL-path that relative path *substitutions* are relative to. (In much the same way as the `BASE` HTML tag sets the base URL-path for relative client-side URLs.)

Likewise, if you use mod_rewrite directives in a `<Directory>` container (again, a *directory* context) in the server config then these behave the same as when used in `.htaccess` and the `RewriteBase` directive can apply here also. This is the easiest way to migrate directives from `.htaccess` to the "server config". Simply place the same directives in a corresponding `<Directory>` container and nothing else to change. (You should also probably disable the use of `.htaccess` entirely if you do this.)

However, in a *server* or *virtualhost* context (which is processed before the *directory* context directives and before the request has been mapped to the filesystem) all URL-paths should be treated as relative to the document-root and should be expressed as root-relative - starting with a slash.

#### For example...

In a `.htaccess` file located at `/some-directory/.htaccess` (relative to the document-root):

```
# .htaccess
RewriteBase /yourname
RewriteRule ^url-path-to-match$ substitution-string [L]
```

The `RewriteBase` directive only applies to *relative* `substitution-string` arguments (ie. that do not start with a slash or scheme+hostname). It does not apply to the `url-path-to-match` (which is always relative to the current directory in a *directory* context - no slash prefix).

So, the above would internally rewrite a request from `/some-directory/url-path-to-match` to `/yourname/substitution-string`.

If you want to do the same in a *server* or *virtualhost* context then you need to remove the `RewriteBase` directive and explicitly state the root-relative URL-paths:

```
# Server
RewriteRule ^/some-directory/url-path-to-match$ /yourname/substitution-string [L]
```

---

### Additional...

Note that removing the `RewriteBase` directive isn't the only change required when moving directives from `.htaccess` to the server config. Since the directives are processed before the request is mapped to the file-system any server variables that relate to the file-system, such as `REQUEST_FILENAME`, are not going to be set yet and you need to use *lookaheads* (eg. `LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME`). (`REQUEST_FILENAME` contains the same as `REQUEST_URI` when used in a server context, ie. the root-relative URL-path, not the filesystem path.)

Also, the rewrite engine does not loop (pass-through) as it does in a *directory* context. This must be explicitly triggered (if required) using the `PT` flag.